# How to shift a node text upwards one line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have two types of rectangle nodes, each hosting two lines of text inside.

- The first type of node must be 3 lines high, with the 2 lines of text being the first two ones (the main constraint is actually that the second line must be vertically centered within the node);
- The second type of node must be only 2 lines high, with the text vertically centered as usual.

Due to some obscure codebase managing patterns, **I am restricted to doing this by only changing the node style**.

Here are sketches of what I'd like to obtain:

```
First type of node:                Second type of node:
┌─────────────┐                    ┌─────────────┐
│ First line  │                    │ First line  │
│ Second line │                    │ Second line │
│             │                    └─────────────┘
└─────────────┘
```

The second type of node is made easily using a double backslash for the line break; the text is then automatically vertically centered as expected.

On the other hand, I am  struggling to build a node looking like the first one.

- I have tried **using labels** but I cannot figure how to put them *inside* the node, and moreover they won't make the node expand to host the full label as the node text does.
- I have thought of **shifting the node text upwards**, but I have not succeeded. I have only found the `shift` option, that shifts the whole node (text and rectangle shape), which is not what I want.
- Finally, I've tried **using *execute at end node***, like this: `execute at end node=\\` but this does not work either (I have checked that `execute at end node=foobar` actually works as expected to be sure not to miss anything syntax-related).

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand, what you want. You write that the two line node is as you want it, so I do not understand the problem here.

```
\documentclass[tikz, 11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, align=left] (A) at (0,0) {First line\\Second line\\}; %Empty third line
\node[draw, align=left, text depth=\baselineskip] (B) at (3,0) {First line\\Second line}; %Only two lines
\draw[red, dashed] (A.north west) -- (B.north east);
\draw[red, dashed] (A.south west) -- (B.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two nodes with two lines of tex and an empty line]

**Edit:** The same thing in a style:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
twoline/.style={draw, align=left},
threeline/.style={draw, align=left, text depth=\baselineskip},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[threeline] (A) at (0,0) {First line\\Second line};
\node[twoline] (B) at (3,0) {First line\\Second line};
\draw[red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two nodes with text]

Comment: The OP wants e.g. `\node [twoline] {foo\\bar};` to give a node without the empty line at the end, but `\node[threeline] {foo\\bar};` to give a node with the empty line. So the `text depth` approach might work (I was just on my way to posting an answer using that ...), as that could be wrapped in a style.

Comment: Nice summary of my very convoluted question, thx.

Comment: @Silverspur: I have already put the options in a style, so could you indicate if this answers your question?

Comment: This does perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure what you after. Do you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, 11pt, 
               margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, align=left, anchor= north, 
            text depth=#1\baselineskip  % number of empty lines after text
            },
N/.default = 0
                        ]
\node[N=1] (A)          {First line\\Second line}; %Empty third line
\node[N]   (B) at (3,0) {First line\\Second line}; 
\node[N]   (C) at (6,0) {First line};
\node[N=3] (D) at (9,0) {First line};

\draw[red, dashed] (A.north west) -- (D.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- If nodes not need to be aligned at their top, than delete node's option `anchor=north`.
- In cases of relative positioning of nodes with aligned their tops, than nodes anchor should be changed to `anchor=north west` and node positioned by `\node[right=of <name i>.north east, N] (name j) {...};`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 11pt, 
               margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, align=left, anchor=north west, 
            text depth=#1\baselineskip  % number of empty lines after text
            },
N/.default = 0
                        ]
\node[N=1]  (A) {First line\\Second line}; %Empty third line
\node[right=of A.north east,
      N]    (B) {First line\\Second line}; 
\node[right=of B.north east,
      N]    (C) {First line};
\node[right=of C.north east,
      N=2]  (B) {First line\\Second line};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, align=left, 
            text depth=#1\baselineskip  % number of empty lines after text
            },
N/.default = 0
                        ]
\node[N=1]  (A) {First line\\Second line}; %Empty third line
\node[right=of A,
      N]    (B) {First line\\Second line};
\node[right=of B,
      N]    (C) {First line};
\node[right=of C,
      N=2]  (B) {First line\\Second line};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]